# Windows 10 гробит файлы если нет места?

Tags: windows, файлы, windows-10

Столкнулся с тем, что закончилось место на системном диске - совсем закончилось - 0 байт. При это пострадали 5 файлов из Downloads. Но странно то, как именно они пострадали.

Размер файлов был от 1 до 3 ГБ. Они были скачаны более месяца назад и стех пор не должны были меняться. Про один из них точно изсестно, что он был рабочий.

А вот, что произошло:

1. Все файлы стали [sparse-файлами](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB) и стали занимать на диске около 200 МБ.
2. Все три даты (создания, изменения и открытия) поменялись на нечто очень близкое к моменту, когда закончилось место на системном диске.
3. Все файлы битые и начинаются с большого количества нулей.
4. Место при этом не освободилось, но это может быть связано с тем, что новые файлы постоянно создавались (место кончилось из-за того, что я случайно запустил скачивание торрента с большим числом файлов и объёмом, превышающим свободное место).
5. `chkdsk` не нашёл никаких проблем с файловой системой.

Единственное логичное объяснение - что десятка попыталась преобразованием файлов в разряженные освободить место, но у неё это по каким-то причинам не вышло (файлы испортились). С другой стороны, я весьма сильно сомневаюсь, что такое действие с произвольными файлами позволит освободить много места.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такими проблемами и как их можно избежать? Если моя догадка верна, может быть есть какой-то параметр, отключающий такое поведение? А то это совсем не дело, чтобы давно лежащие файлы порсто так гробились за то, что они большие. Насколько я понимаю, восстановить файлы в такой ситуации возможности нет.

И может ли такое произойти с файлами на других дисках?

[image: скриншот новых свойств файла]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67810/discussion-on-question-by-qwertiy-windows-10-----).